# Reference in sql parameter

Tags: c#

I have this warning, but I don't know why. Have you any ideas:

> Warning : Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value
>   comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Code:

```
ComTelo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KOD_ZBOZI", 
            ((object)(dataRadek.ItemArray[6]).ToString()) == string.Empty ? System.DBNull.Value : (object)(dataRadek.ItemArray[6]).ToString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that because of `((object)(dataRadek.ItemArray[6]).ToString()) == string.Empty`. This casts the string to object, causing the comparison to be a reference comparison, not that of the string value.

Just remove the cast to `object`:

```
string item6Value = dataRadek.ItemArray[6]).ToString();

ComTelo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KOD_ZBOZI", 
            item6Value == "" ? System.DBNull.Value : item6Value;
```

Comment: @jane  If yoiu really want to just check if a string is empty or null you could also use string.IsNullOrEmpty(myStringName). I found that quite useful instead of using "" or string.empty comparisons by hand.